# Migré un sistema en laravel pero no se visualizan los datos de la base de datos

Tags: laravel

no soy experta en laravel pero migré el sistema sin problemas y migré la base de datos, hice la conexión en el archivo .env y generé el

```php
php artisan migrate
```

Al ingresar al sistema no se visualizan los datos, hice una prueba creando un datos y se guarda en la base de datos pero aun así no logro ver los datos ya almacenados.

Pueden ayudarme porfis

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ejecutaste antes un `php artisan migrate:status`?

Comment: Si y todo salía correcto

Comment: Puedes compartir el codigo de como estas intentando mostrar los datos que tienes almacenado en tu BD ?

Comment: El comando `php artisan migrate` solo ejecuta crea las tablas en la base de datos, no le introduce valores, para eso podrías crear [seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/seeding) para llenar tus tablas con datos falsos mientras vas creando tu proyecto para ir haciendo pruebas, para ejecutar los seeder se usa `php artisan db:seed`. Lo otro es que deberías compartir los métodos que usas para manejar los datos porque sin eso no podremos ayudarte a indentificar y resolver el problema